# How to make a GUI for first-order logic representation?

Tags: reference-request, logic, graphics, knowledge-representation

This idea blows my mind, I would appreciate for any guidance. In essence, the question is how a machine should work to transform any kind of formal logic into its graphical representation (e.g. conceptual graph)? And moreover, from graphs into linear form.

I have heard about ISO standard for Common Logic framework. It is about the way how to transform human-readable formalism into machine interface. Suppose that I am using XML notation for Common Logic (XCL). In general, by what means could a communication between human and machine be provide? To say, I have a formalism, then I am getting a picture; or vice versa, I have a picture, then a computer, parsing it, composes a linear form. It resembles Protégé ontology editor, but I am interested in how this is programmatically implemented.

I would like to know what technologies are engaged in conversion of a linear form into graph: its names, so I could learn corresponding literature.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are asking.  You seem to assume that there is one unique/standard way to convert formal logic into a graph.  I don't think that is correct.  There might be many ways to do such a conversion, depending on your goals.  Can you [edit] your question to be more specific about what your problem is?

Comment: What do you mean by "linear form"? I'd start out by listing the things the user of your application are supposed to be able to do.